# Is there any setting should i do for ios flutter cloud messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notifications to my flutter app.

I tested android and it worked perfectly. However, ios did not work out.
Is there any progress work that I should do for the ios setting?
I did not register for the apple developer program yet.

Please help out. Somebody help me....

I will leave the code below

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:firebase_in_app_messaging/firebase_in_app_messaging.dart';

class NotificationPresenter extends GetxController {
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

@override
void onInit() async{
NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
  alert: true,
  announcement: true,
  badge: true,
  carPlay: true,
  criticalAlert: true,
  provisional: true,
  sound: true,
);
print(settings.authorizationStatus);
_getToken();
_onMessage();
super.onInit();
}
void _getToken() async{
String? token= await messaging.getToken();
try{
  print(token);
} catch(e) {}
}
final AndroidNotificationChannel channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
'high_importance_channel', // id
'High Importance Notifications', // title
description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
importance: Importance.max,
);
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
void _onMessage() async{
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
    .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
    ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    const InitializationSettings(
        android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'), iOS: IOSInitializationSettings()),
    onSelectNotification: (String? payload) async {});

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;

  if (notification != null && android != null) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
            channelDescription: channel.description
        ),
      ),
      // payload: message.data['argument']
    );
  }
  print('foreground 상황에서 메시지를 받았다.');
  print('Message data: ${message.data}');
  if (message.notification != null) {
    print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification!.body}');
  }
});
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using iOS simulator?

Comment: yeah i am using iOS simulator

Comment: Notifications do not work is iOS simulator. Please use a physical device instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few steps in case of ios

1. Registering a bundle id
2. Registering a provision profile
3. Enabling push notification service for that profile
4. Generating an apns (Apple push notification service) key
5. Adding this apns to firebase
6. Creating an ios id in firebase
7. Downloading the Google service info plist and adding it to the project

These steps are all required to recieve push notification in ios

Answer (score 0):

[Follow this step for flutter integration](https://medium.com/@jun.chenying/flutter-tutorial-part3-push-notification-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-2fbdd84d3a5e) for setting up the APN certificate with cloud messaging

[Set up for certificate and APNs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/)

After completing certification step download the GoogleService-Info.plist and add it using Xcode.